# Cannot call a class as a function in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Hi I am trying to follow ES6 syntax to create a middleware of my node.js application.

index.js

```
export default class Middleware {
  constructor() {
    //do nothing
  }

  fun1 = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    console.log("AAa");
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    next();
  };

  fun2 = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    console.log("AAa");
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    next();
  };
}
```

app.js

```
import Middleware from ".index";
app.use(Middleware);
```

I am getting an error Cannot call a class as a function. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: when I remove `app.use(Middleware);` then it works

Comment: Is this using the express framework?

Comment: You have to add `new` keyword when you are calling a class, try  `app.use(new Middleware);`

Comment: It’s telling you wants wrong - you can’t use a class here. `app.use()` is expecting a function with a particular signature.

Comment: @todes When I add new then I am getting TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express `app#use` expects a function with the following signature:

```
function(req, res, next) {
```

To make it work, you need to do:

1. Create an instance of `Middleware` class.
2. Register middleware for each function in the class.

Example:

```
let middleware = new Middleware();

app.use(middleware.func1);
app.use(middleware.func2);
```